# Como preencher um textbox com um LIKE do MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

Estou tentando preencher o textbox, quando o cliente for digitando as iniciais do seu Nome, o select vai no banco e tentar buscar as informações. Porém, não tenho ideia de como mandar

Vou mostrar pra vcs como está minha View e meu DAL.

View:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label>Nome</label><asp:TextBox  ID="txbAlgNome" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

</div>
<div>
        <asp:Button ID="button_cad_1"  runat="server" Text="Salvar" onclick="button1_cad_veiculo" />
</div>
```

Codigo do view:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Geax1.Model;
using Geax1.DAL;

namespace Geax1.Views
{
  public partial class AluguelVeiculos : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //enviando o nome para o SELECT no meu DAL
        _AluguelVeiculos aldata = new _AluguelVeiculos();

        aldata.Nomecliente1 = txbAlgNome.Text;

        _ListaNome.ListaNomeCliente(aldata);


        //preenchendo os campos do TextBox, após o select Like
        txbAlgNome.DataBinding = _ListaNome.retornaNomecliente();

      }
    }
  }
```

Meu DAL:

```
namespace Geax1.DAL
{
  public class _ListaNome
  {
    private static List<_AluguelVeiculos> lc = new List<_AluguelVeiculos>();

    public static void ListaNomeCliente(_AluguelVeiculos obj)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;Database=xpto;User ID=root;Password='';"))
        {

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT nome, cpf FROM tab_cliente WHERE nome LIKE '%nome% ;", conn);

            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);

            foreach (DataRow linha in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                _AluguelVeiculos cl_1 = new _AluguelVeiculos();

                cl_1.Nomecliente1 = Convert.ToString(linha["nome"]);
                cl_1.CpfCliente1 = Convert.ToString(linha["cpf"]);

                lc.Add(cl_1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<_AluguelVeiculos> retornaNomecliente() 
    {
        _AluguelVeiculos al = new _AluguelVeiculos();
        ListaNomeCliente(al);
        return lc;
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Assim? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Sim, dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira sugerida pela Microsoft aconselha você a instalar o [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/), embora seja possível (com uma dificuldade maior) usar o jQuery UI e bolar suas próprias requisições AJAX.

Pela maneira do AJAX Control Toolkit (que eu acho a mais interessante porque seu projeto é em Web Forms), a implementação seria usando um componente chamado [`AutoCompleteExtender`](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) e [programando um WebMethod para fazer uma chamada na sua DAL](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx). Como o roteiro é muito grande, não vale a pena colocar numa resposta, mas você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar os pontos em que você tem dúvida, que vou respondendo.

Comment: Valeu, Cigano. Mais uma vez, você me ajudando. Vou da uma olhada no Ajax Control.